# How to fix this MongoClient connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, yandexcloud

I'm trying to connect a node.js app (written in TS) to MongoDB at Yandex Cloud. I have successfully connected there via `mongosh`:

```
mongosh "mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/?replicaSet=<rs>&authSource=<db>&ssl=true" \
   --tls --tlsCAFile ./YandexInternalRootCA.crt
```

where YandexInternalRootCA.crt is the downloaded certificate. Now I'm trying to do the same via `MongoClient` like this (the code is adapted from their examples; node v15.14.0, mongodb ^4.1.2):

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from 'mongodb'
import fs from 'fs'

const connnectionString = '<same connection string as the above argument of mongosh>'
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    replSet: {
        sslCA: fs.readFileSync('./YandexInternalRootCA.crt')
    },
    //tlsInsecure: true,
}

const getStorage = async (): Promise<Db> => {
    // ts-ignore here is due to some typing problem: once you use 2 arguments
    // in .connect, TS shows that it promises void (which is not true)
    // @ts-ignore
    return (await MongoClient.connect(connnectionString, options)).db()
}
```

Unexectedly, this results in

> MongooseServerSelectionError: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I've tried to add `tlsInsecure` where it is show commented out (from [suggestion](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9147) for Mongoose), but it doesn't make a difference. What can be the cause and how can I fix this?

PS I've also tried various things like

```
const getStorage = async (): Promise<Db> => {
    return (await MongoClient.connect(config.mongo.connectionUri, {
        tls: true,
        //sslCA: fs.readFileSync('./YandexInternalRootCA.crt'),
        tlsCertificateFile: './YandexInternalRootCA.crt',
        tlsInsecure: true,
    })).db()
}
```

which still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mongodb` npm package version 4 or higher, you should pass TLS options like this:

```
const options = {
    tls: true,
    tlsCAFile: './YandexInternalRootCA.crt'
}
```